# Number of elements in a multiplicative group of $ (complex)^{2^n} $ th roots of unity for a specific n.

Tags: complex-numbers, finite-groups

The number of elements of the multiplicative group $ (complex)^n $ th roots of unity is n .But  for a fixed n the number of elements in a multiplicative group of $ (complex)^{2^n}$ th roots of unity is also n .I didn't know that I thought it's $ 2^n $ but few days ago I saw someone wrote  $ G_{2^n} =\{e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{2^n}}  \mid k=0,1,2,...n-1\} $ which means there are n elements .So Is there a definition I mean what about the number of elements of the multiplicative group $ (complex)^{4^3} $ th roots of unity is it 64 or 6 or 3.
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to edit your post to make it readable.  Did I get it right?  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you sir. .will you please tell me the answer?

Comment: please someone give me a hint  or suggest be a book please

Comment: Why do you think there would be only $n$ $2^n$th roots of unity? That's nonsense! There are clearly $2^n$ elements in that group. Somebody just made a typo when describing the range of the parameter $k$.

Comment: Thank you so much  and I will be grateful to you for ever since I couldn't concentrate on anything since yesterday. Actually when I saw the mistake I commented on that post  but no one answered and the person didn't edit  the question  and then someone else did the same thing ..so I thought there is a tiny possibility that I am wrong and I should ask the experts  and so did I.Thank you again.